# Regex International Phone numbers allowing white spaces

Tags: regex, whitespace, phone-number

I'm trying to get a regex to validate international phone numbers.

This is what i have so far:

```
 ^\+?( |\(|\))*?\d{8,14}$
```

What I'm aiming for is total allowed digits is 8-14. In addition, to allow as many whitespace and dashes in between, after or before the digits.

Examples:

```
12345678901234
123    456789  0 1 2 3 4
+1       2345678901234
(12)  3   4   56  7  8   9 01234
1-2-3-4-5-6-7 8 9 0 123     4
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: @Avinash There you go.

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mP5dO4/1

Comment: You must be a regx god lol. Thank you very much Avinash Raj.

Comment: no, there are many powerful regex gods than me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would help you.

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d\D*){8,14}$)[ -]*\+?[ -]*(?:\((?:[ -]*\d)+[ -]*\))?[- \d]*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mP5dO4/3)

OR

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d\D*){8,14}$)[- \d()+]*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mP5dO4/1)

`\D` matches any non-digit character. `(?=(?:\D*\d\D*){8,14}$)` asserts that the string we are going to match must contain 8 to 14 digit.